# how to set Edit Textbox cursor start to some default position?

Tags: android, android-cursor

im using a edittext box drawable where the border is little graphical like it has two line border.the thing is if i enter the text its overlapping with the edge of the box.how can i create a space/ gap in the beginning,so that i can enter the text after 1/2 spaces gap from the left end.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textId);
editText.setText("EditText component");
editText.setSelection(3);
```

try this code to set cursor to position 3.

If you just want to add space at strting try adding paddingLeft attribute in your code.

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks,I have tried with the way you hav told ,but i dint get the required results,can anyone find a soulution for this.